# Caracter de Select

Tags: html, css, icono

De ante mano me disculpo si no deberia de hacer esta "Pregunta", alguien tiene o sabe donde puedo encontrar el icono que sale de los select ?

necesito tener el mismo icono para ponérselo a un boton ...

necesito el caracter, no iconos, no imágenes gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, en [esta página](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/down%20arrow) puedes encontrar lo que necesitas. `⌄` (&# 8964;) Todo junto

Comment: Te lo puse en el comentario anterior. El código del caracter está entre paréntesis, escríbelo todo junto adentro de una etiqueta `<p>` por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin más que decir porque no me corresponde, el icono puedes encontrarlo en [Octicons](https://primer.style/octicons/chevron-down-16)

Comment: Gracias, solo necesitaba eso